# Why use "at" in this way?

Tags: zero-article, signage, locatives

I always see signs such as

> Men at work

or

> Children at play

I was wondering why we use "at" in this way. Is it just a formal way of saying *Men Working* / *Children Playing*?

Saying "At Lunch" seems sensible, yet even so I would only use this if I were out of the office etc, I wouldnt say "I'm at lunch" if I weren't changing location. If I were to say "I'm *At Work*" I would use this to inform someone I am at my workplace, not that I am actually working, and no one I know would say their children are "At Play" rather than "Playing".

*At* to me has always seemed more a word used with a location rather than an action.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer might be well out of scope of this site. English hasn't invented using *at* this way. Many languages have identical (*at*) or very similar (*in* or *on*) constructions.

Comment: Maybe the point of the question is: Since you wouldn't say "Children at swim," what's so special about "work" and "play" that we can use this construction?

Comment: I agree with @RegDwight that using _at_ in that way is not a prerogative of English. Italian would use the equivalent of _at_ in the same way (_uomini al lavoro_).

Comment: In Portuguese of Portugal, this method is generally preferred over the gerund-participle.  You _would_ say "Estou a nadar" (I'm at swim).  In Brazil, the opposite is true.  You would say "Estou nadando" (I'm swimming).  It's just the way people say things.

Comment: @Peter Shor Thanks thats one of the points I was wanting to make

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "because that is how we use it". It sounds circular, but constructions like these are arbitrary.  It seems that your main difficulty with this construction comes with the assumption you make in your last sentence:

> *At* to me has always seemed more a word used with a location rather than an action.

Other uses of *at* that are not locative:

> - I am mad at you.
> - He was at peace with his decision.
> - The effort was amateur at best.
> - See you at 5 o'clock.

There are actually lots and lots of non-locative uses for *at*. From these examples, I am sure you can think of many more.

Maybe we should actually ask why *at* is ever used as a locative, since we have *in*, *on*, *by* and *to*? :)

Comment: Is the descriptive term for this 'idiomatic'?

Comment: @Mitch: No, an idiomatic usage is one that is particular to a certain phrase, or that cannot be broken down into its individual words (e.g. the meaning of "kick the bucket" cannot be understood by simply looking at the definitions of "kick" and "bucket"). This is a preposition with more than one meaning.

Answer (score 1):

*At* is also used to denote the time spent by someone attending an educational institution, a workplace, their home, etc.

> We all need to get involved in fighting crime whether it's at work, at home, or at school.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, 'at' can mean doing something. For example: 'Did you do your homework?' reply: 'Yes, I was at it all night.' Did you fix the car?' reply: 'Yes, I've been at it all morning.'meaning doing it all night / all morning. So your examples above mean 'Men doing work.' or 'Children doing the activity of play.'

Answer (score 0):

It's the same usage of 'at' that you see in the expression "Have *at* it".  It's a way of indicating not a place but a state typically revolving around an activity.  Normally when you indicate a state, you simply use a form of to be with that state (I'm sleepy for example), however whenever you *cannot* indicate your state in such a fashion for risking to have other meanings, you typically see at used (for example, you can't say "I'm work", but rather "I'm at work.").

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I hear "at" as a synonym for "engaged in".