# Which is right and why: Why do people go (to zoos/to zoo/to the zoo)?

Tags: articles, questions, definite-articles, zero-article, locatives

I couldn’t find these explanation of exactly how the rules of articles apply in questions like this:

- Why do people go to zoos?
- Why do people go to zoo?
- Why do people go to the zoo?

It’s not a question about a specific zoo, but about zoos in general.

The first variant sounds correct, but I’m not so sure about the second and third.

Are there scenarios in which both are acceptable, such as spoken English versus formal writing?

Comment: I'll leave the question about article rules to a non-native speaker or someone more experienced in the nuances of diction since my knowledge about when articles are and aren't used is basically 100% instinct and I've always been terrible at explaining it. However, I can tell you that the 2nd example is never used while the third example generally has the same meaning as the first.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2031 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19604 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/137476 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/113448 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/67036 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/140896 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/18268

Comment: This has nothing to do with questions.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry, but I'm still a bit confused. I am not entirely convinced my answer is there in those links.

Comment: If I prefix the phrases you added in my question statement with "I like" - I can see a similarity. But "I like going to the zoo" suggests a particular zoo and I'm not really sure if the "the" in "Why do people go to the zoo?" refers to a particular zoo or not. Can you clear that up?

Comment: @Ankush: Both current answers here are AmE native speakers - one seems to agree with your "logical" inference that *children going to the zoo* implies some *particular* zoo, the other doesn't. I think it's just that (some?) Americans tend towards more "stringent, literal" interpretations. Most Brits would class that usage alongside *going to the cinema* (where we don't really care *which* cinema it is, any more than we care which particular films are being referenced by *going to the movies*).

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Thanks!

Also, 2 downvotes. I didn't realize the question was *that* useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why do people go to zoos* is correct and would be my choice.

*Why do people go to zoo* is grammatically incorrect, because the singular "zoo" is missing an article.

*Why do people go to the zoo* is grammatically correct but a bit odd.  Colloquially, the phrase "go to the zoo" does not imply any particular zoo; for example, the sentence "why does a person go to the zoo?" is perfectly correct.  But with the plural subject "people", I think using "zoos" (plural) is more correct, unless you mean a group of people all going to the same zoo.

Comment: It's at least *possible* (though I don't actually know) that Americans are less keen on *going to the zoo* than Brits. But [*children go to the zoo more frequently than they go to Disneyland*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22children+go+to+the+zoo+more+frequently%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is fine by me, and was most likely penned by an AmE writer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm american and we always used the phrase *going to the zoo* when I was growing up.  I don't know about americans in general.

Comment: "go to the zoo" is an extremely common phrase in AmE and is usually used in the form of a question: "Do you want to go to the zoo?" [Ngram support.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+to+the+zoo%2C+go+to+zoos&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20the%20zoo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20zoos%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @MrHen Of course it is, but in your example ("Do you want to go to the zoo?") and in all the examples I can think of, it is a single person or a group of people going to the *same zoo*.  In this case,  I really doubt *Why do people go to the zoo* is completely acceptable, because you are talking about multiple zoos.

Comment: I guess then, this variant is best avoided since there is an alternative people can agree is perfectly correct ( _Why do people go to zoos?_ )

Answer (score 4):

The first and third options are correct in American English:

> Why do people go to zoos?
>
> Why do people go to the zoo?

The second is incorrect and should be avoided.